# Laravel canot register for new uses

Tags: laravel-5

I am creating a simple login function on my website with a registration feature. The registration feature is functional and users are appearing in the database. However, when I try to register new user, it did not inserted into database and stay on the same page and refresh data in form register. When I enter credentials, be it correct or wrong, the page would just reload with no error messages.

This is my 'register.blade.php'

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header text-center h2">{{ __('Register') }}</div>

            <div class="card-body">
                <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                    @csrf

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="text" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('First Name') }}</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="fname" type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" required autocomplete="first-name">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="text" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Last Name') }}</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="fname" type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" required autocomplete="last-name">
                        </div>
                    </div>




                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email">

                            @error('email')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password">

                            @error('password')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="text" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Position') }}</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="position" type="text" class="form-control" name="postion" required autocomplete="position">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="address" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Address') }}</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="address" type="address" class="form-control @error('address') is-invalid @enderror" name="address" value="{{ old('address') }}" required autocomplete="address">

                            @error('address')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                {{ __('Register') }}
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
@endsection
```

This is my route  web.php

```
  <?php

 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

  /*
   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------


    Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('auth.login');
   });

   Auth::routes();

   Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');


   Route::group(['as'=>'admin.','prefix'=>'admin','namespace'=>'Admin','middleware'=> 
    ['auth','admin']], function (){

    Route::get('dashboard','DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');

   });
   Route::group(['as'=>'author.','prefix'=>'author','namespace'=>'Author','middleware'=> 
   ['auth','author']], function (){
   Route::get('dashboard','DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');
   Route::post('register', 'RegisterController@register');  
   });
```

This is my RegisterController

```
   namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
   use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
   use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

   class RegisterController extends Controller
   {
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Controller
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
| validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
| provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
|
*/

use RegistersUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after registration.
 *
 * @var string
 */
 protected $redirectTo;
/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role->id == 1){
        $this -> redirectTo = route('admin.dashboard');
    }else {
        $this -> redirectTo = route('author.dashboard');
    }
    $this->middleware('guest');
}

/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'first_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'last_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'address' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'position' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \App\User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'role_id' => 2,
        'first_name' => $data['name'],
        'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
        'address' => $data['address'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'positin' => $data['position'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);   
  }    
 }
```

This my route list

```
     +--------+----------+------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                    | Name             | Action                                                                 | Middleware      |
+--------+----------+------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /                      |                  | Closure                                                                | web             |
|        | GET|HEAD | admin/dashboard        | admin.dashboard  | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\DashboardController@index                   | web,auth,admin  |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user               |                  | Closure                                                                | api,auth:api    |
|        | GET|HEAD | author/dashboard       | author.dashboard | App\Http\Controllers\Author\DashboardController@index                  | web,auth,author |
|        | GET|HEAD | home                   | home             | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                              | web,auth        |
|        | GET|HEAD | login                  | login            | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                | web,guest       |
|        | POST     | login                  |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login                        | web,guest       |
|        | POST     | logout                 | logout           | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout                       | web             |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/confirm       | password.confirm | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ConfirmPasswordController@showConfirmForm    | web,auth        |
|        | POST     | password/confirm       |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ConfirmPasswordController@confirm            | web,auth        |
|        | POST     | password/email         | password.email   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail  | web,guest       |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/reset         | password.request | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm | web,guest       |
|        | POST     | password/reset         | password.update  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset                | web,guest       |
|        | GET|HEAD | password/reset/{token} | password.reset   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm        | web,guest       |
|        | GET|HEAD | register               | register         | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm      | web,guest       |
|        | POST     | register               |                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register                  | web,guest       |
+--------+----------+------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
virakran@Lenovo-ideapad:~/Desktop/StudentFollowupG6$
```

Comment: have you checked error log in logs file?

Comment: Also you are calling register method for route while that method doesn't exist in your controller. You have to call create method and use Request $request in param of method.

Comment: @UmairMalik  Thank you for reply . I am not yet to check it.

Comment: @UmairMalik  Thank you very much. I will try to create method for register